# VHDL non-sequential pins

Tags: verilog, fpga, gpio

I am a novice with VHDL so I am working with existing code.  In the top level code, the ports are assigned as follows:

```
.conduit_gpio_set_0   (GPIO_0[31 : 16]).
```

My FPGA board has a GPIO_0 and GPIO_1 bank. I made a PCB board that uses 16 pins but they are not consecutive as seen by the FPGA. What is the syntax for assigning 16 pins to say.... GPIO_0[32 and 30 : 16] ? I have tried many different formats with no success.

Comment: Your top-level code looks like Verilog to me, not VHDL.

Comment: For altera fpga and Quartus Prima suite, you assign port-to-pin mapping in separate "assignment editor" or "pin planner". I assume the same is available from your development suite, which you didn't mention.

Comment: It is Verilog. My bad.  Vlad, I am going back to the pin planner. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to use a concatenation when instatiating, like this?

```
.conduit_gpio_set_0({GPIO_0[32], GPIO_0[30:16]}).
```

Assuming GPIO_0 is 33 bits wide (or wider).